# Mandrill not sent HTML Emails with WooCommerce plugin

Tags: html, wordpress, email, woocommerce, mandrill

In my online store created in WooCommerce with Mandrill plugin for sending new orders, order status and order complete, however all emails, correctly formatted in HTML, arrive in text mode to the recipients.
I've tried various settings, all to without sucess.
If I disable the Mandrill, all emails are sent in HTML.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

left: received email | right: Mandrill settings

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oewwH.png

Comment: You'll probably want to take a look at the [API Logs](https://mandrillapp.com/settings/api) for your Mandrill account to see what is being passed to Mandrill, since it's possible you have some incorrectly-formatted HTML that's causing that type of display. Alternately, can you add the original HTML as well as the received HTML to the original post to be able to see whether there are any issues with the HTML being passed? Also, what settings do you have enabled for the wpMandrill plugin?

Comment: Hello Kaitlin.
His answer reminded me of one thing I had not checked! Plugin settings within the Wordpress. I very much appreciate your help, with it I discovered the error.
I had enabled the option "Replace all line feeds ("\n") by <br/> in the message body?". As the WooCommerce already formats the HTML correctly, the plugin was changing the correct formatting.
Once again, thank you!